# codeigniter form POST Empty in Controller from View

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess, codeigniter, post

I'm working with Codeigniter. I have created an HTML form which post data to the Controller.

This Form was working perfectly but it suddenly stopped posting data.

**HTML:**

```
<form name="frm_search" id="frm_search" method="post" action="http://ip/free/index.php/taskdetails/tabOne/1/ShibNo/asc/">
<input  id="order1" name="order1" value="26" type="text" >
<input  id="item1" name="item1" value="" type="text" >
</form>
```

1. I tried to check the data post in Browser and it shows the data that I input in the input box.

[image]

2. In My index.php I placed the following code to see if it is posted:

> ```
> echo "CONTENT_TYPE: " . $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] . "";
> $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
> echo "DATA: <pre>";
> var_dump($data);
> var_dump($_POST);
> echo "</pre>"; 
> exit;
> ```

**RESULT:**

> CONTENT_TYPE: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> string 'order1=26&item1='
>
> array (size=23)
>   'order1' => string '26' (length=2)
>    'item1' => string '' (length=0)

But when I print $_POST in controller I get the following:

```
Array
(
    [order1] => 
    [item1] =>
)
```

3. My .htaccess code as follows:

   > ```
   > RewriteEngine on
   >
   > RewriteCond $1 !^(index\\.php|resources|robots\\.txt)
   >
   > RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   >
   > RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   >
   > RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
   > ```

Can someone tell me what's the issue? I'm not able to find out why is it when the data passes to controller it becomes null. The application was running successfully for more than a year but I got this issue suddenly.

Thank you in advance. Kindly let me know if you need any more to help me.

**Note:** I figured out that once the page is loaded, If I edit the name of the input  to some other name then the data is post successfully.

**i.e:** instead of **order1**, If I change the name my editing using inspect element in Chrome to "**neworder**" Then if I submit, the data submits with value to controller. Don't know why?

**Update:** I found some this strange. In the set-cookie of the browser. It's like a full page of junk.

Each time when the page is called i start a new session but i wont kill the existing session. Is that a problem?

Even If i destroy the old session and start new one I get eh set-cookies in browser. It has to me one.. but in my case I get more than 6 set cookies in the browser.

Comment: Maybe u r using order1 somewhere

Comment: What CodeIgniter version? Do you have XSS filtering turned on? Try making `order1 = HELLO`. What does `echo $this->input->post('order1');` produce?

Comment: Do you have some jQuery running on the page which is doing `$('#order1').val('');` or anything like that?

Comment: No Nothing like that. I tired giving different values but still no answer. Yes have Jquery in the page but not for order val.

Comment: did you try to var_dump($_GET)
just out of curiousity - because the data are at some place

or maybe you've somewhere a redirect without knowing it - 
just edit the index.php and make a var_dump on top and let the script die after that

Comment: @sintakonte i did that already and posted in my question as well.

Comment: oh sorry i thought you were talking about your controller (totally overlooked  that) - so the problem is CI related
in your controller did you try to execute something like $this->input->input_stream('item1') and whats the outcome of this ? because if this is empty too i really think you might have a redirect

Comment: Have you tried enabling the profiler to see what data is submitted? Add `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);` at the start of your controller method to do so.

Comment: @petervanloo yes i did that but i dont see the value posted in tht. empty post array.

Comment: @TomPHP please could you show the full view file as well as the controller? Such of issue happens for duplicate name of input field? Moreover, is it ajax request?

Comment: No it is not an ajax.. but in ajax also i tried but tis not working :(

Comment: Sorry the view file is of 2300 lines cant post in stack .. :( I am using html form only.. i am not creating form in codeignator..

Comment: Well, *something* is modifying your `$_POST` array at runtime and CodeIgniter doesn't do that by default. We obviously couldn't review your thousands lines of code, but we can't blindly guess the reason either ...

Comment: @Narf can u check my update.

Comment: [That update](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35756622/revisions) is very unclear and has nothing to do with the original question ...

Comment: Please print this in your controller:   $this->input->post(NULL)

Comment: @TomPHP how you pass this?? AJAX?? post that too

Comment: No AJAX.. and also tried with AJAX when it didnt worked.. but didnt worked both ways..

Comment: how you are passing it to controller???

Comment: @TomPHP asnwer this [comment question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35756622/codeigniter-form-post-empty-in-controller-from-view#comment60013656_35756622)

Comment: Have you set your base url some times if you leave it blank will not submit form.

Comment: Please post at least the relevant portions of your controller code. The problem is evidently not in any of the sections you have posted.

Comment: As usual post.. @Abdulla

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be a .htaccess issue with RewriteRule, according to this CI github post issue https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/242:

> if Apache server is used then mod rewrite should be enabled, otherwise
>   redirection will be proper but with empty $_POST.

&

> if you don't have a trailing slash on your URL the server will send a
>   301 redirect which will interfere with POST data.

Your problem could be with

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Try changing to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

(from: [not able get post form submit values in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786013/not-able-get-post-form-submit-values-in-codeigniter)) or try to set:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Try in to remove the `www.`from base URL in the `config.php`, extracted from here (very similar issue): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143654/codeigniter-post-variable-empty or check this other too if this not works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201815/codeigniter-post-data-empty

Comment: I still think it could be a .htaccess / routes problem, what's your controller name? And the function? could you paste the folder structure or more code (config.php., route.php...)?

Answer (score 1):

Hi as par my research about this problem is a very unacceptable type but yet I don't know why this is happening or maybe in Codeigniter have some restriction for this kind of problem.

if you described your base URL in config like this, remember at last of URL not included slash:

```
http://ip/free/index.php
```

and on your HTML file on the form tag at the action described like this. remember at last used slash:

```
http://ip/free/index.php/taskdetails/tabOne/1/ShibNo/asc/
```

This is occurring problem to not pass any data to the controller because 'slash' change the path.

In this case, if you did not use a slash at last on-base URL then don't use on HTML form also to make it work.

If you face this kind of problem then once try this might help.

Answer (score 1):

I was with the same error and solve like the answer above.

baseURL in the .env file must contain for production something like

https://www.yourwebsite.com.br/
CodeIgniter 4