# Webhook payload gets sent correctly, but returns empty body

Tags: php, woocommerce, webhooks, codeigniter-4

Hope somebody can help me with this issue.

**Issue:**

I have a woocommerce webhook that fires off when a product gets updated and sends data to a script to store details about the product in a separate database.

When I update a product and check the woocommerce log I can see that the webhook fires and the payload gets delivered correctly, including the body with all the details, such as 'id', 'store_id', 'name' and so on.
However, the response shows a 500 Internal Server error, saying:

`Undefined array key "store_id" in file "ProductController.php" on line 40`

I'm using WooCommerce 8.0.2 and WordPress 6.3.1

**Code:**

Here's part of the code that handles the payload and stores the data.
I'm using CodeIgniter 4.

**ProductController.php**

```
use App\Controllers\BaseController;
use App\Models\WooCommerce\ProductModel;
use CodeIgniter\API\ResponseTrait;

class ProductController extends BaseController{

    use ResponseTrait;

  public function store() {

    //get webhook payload
    $data = $this->request->getPost();

    //populate product data from webhook payload
    $productData = [
        'store_id' => $data['store_id'],        // this is line 40
        'product_id' => $data['product_id']
    ];

    $product = new ProductModel();

    $product=>save($productData);

  }
}
```

**What I've done so far:**

I've tested the webhook payload using Pipedream.com, and I know that the body gets sent and is not empty. The array key "store_id" is right there and has a value.

So where am I losing the data?

I did some research and came about this question [form-post-empty-in-controller-from-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35756622/codeigniter-form-post-empty-in-controller-from-view).
The accepted answer says that it could be a .htaccess issue with RewriteRule according to this CI github post issue https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/242

I'm not very familiar with .htaccess and its RewriteRules, and don't know if that's even causing the issue.

If somebody could have a look at my .htaccess file and see if there's anything that might be causing it, that would be fantastic. Or is there anything else that I should be looking into?

**.htaccess:**

```
# Disable directory browsing
Options -Indexes

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Rewrite engine
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and features.
# FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    RewriteEngine On

    # If you installed CodeIgniter in a subfolder, you will need to
    # change the following line to match the subfolder you need.
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
    # RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to the front controller, index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

    # Ensure Authorization header is passed along
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>

# Disable server signature start
    ServerSignature Off
# Disable server signature end
```

**Edit:**

Here are two screenshots that show that the webhook got delivered. One is from the woocommerce log, and the other when I sent it to pipedream for testing.

WooCommerce log:
[image]

Pipedream.com:
[image]

Comment: _"and I know that the body gets sent and is not empty. The array key "store_id" is right there and has a value."_ - can you show us what that actually looks like? I think the WooCommerce webhooks send JSON, but you are trying to process a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request instead.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for taking your time. I've added two screenshots.

Comment: Yes, it's JSON, so PHP won't populate $_POST (and that is still what CI's `$this->request->getPost();` uses internally, I think) - so you will either have to read the body content from `php://input` and parse it yourself, as shown in [Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18866571/1427878) - or check if CI perhaps already provides a dedicated way to access posted JSON. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/38656283/1427878 for example is a bit closer to the framework, but XSS protection is probably not needed as this point.)

Comment: Great!! It works! I checked and it turns out CI has a way to grab the contents of `php://input` as a JSON stream: `$this->request->getJSON(true)`. Passing the parameter 'true' converts it to associative arrays. Thank you so much. How can I mark/accept your comment as solution to the problem?

Comment: Comments can not be marked as the solution, only answers. But feel free to write up what you found in an answer yourself.

Comment: If that's ok with you, then I'll go ahead and do that. Again, thank very much for taking your time. It really helped a lot.

Comment: Yeah, sure, fine with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to CBroe's comment I got it working.

Here’s how:

The webhook is sending the data as JSON, so CI’s `$this->request->getPost()` won’t populate $_POST. Therefore I got the error message `Undefined array key "store_id"`.

In order to get the data I need to get the content from `php://input` and parse it myself.
Turns out CI already has a dedicated way to do that: `getJSON()`.

By default, this will return any objects in the JSON data as objects. Passing in `true` as the first parameter converts it to associative arrays.

So changing `$this->request->getPost()` to `$this->request->getJSON(true)` in ProductController.php fixed it.